# Compare current column value to different column value by row slices

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Assuming a dataframe like this

```
In [5]: data = pd.DataFrame([[9,4],[5,4],[1,3],[26,7]])                         

In [6]: data                                                                    
Out[6]: 
    0  1
0   9  4
1   5  4
2   1  3
3  26  7
```

I want to count how many times the values in a rolling window/slice of 2 on column 0 are greater or equal to the value in col 1 (4).

On the first number 4 at col 1, a slice of 2 on column 0 yields 5 and 1, so the output would be 2 since both numbers are greater than 4, then on the second 4 the next slice values on col 0 would be 1 and 26, so the output would be 1 because only 26 is greater than 4 but not 1. I can't use rolling window since iterating through rolling window values is not implemented.

I need something like a slice of the previous n rows and then I can iterate, compare and count how many times any of the values in that slice are above the current row.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using `list` instead of doing it in `data frame`. Check the code below:

```
list1, list2 = df['0'].values.tolist(),  df['1'].values.tolist()
outList = []
for ix in range(len(list1)):
    if ix < len(list1) - 2:
        if list2[ix] < list1[ix + 1] and list2[ix] < list1[ix + 2]:
            outList.append(2)
        elif list2[ix] < list1[ix + 1] or list2[ix] < list1[ix + 2]:
            outList.append(1)
        else:
            outList.append(0)
    else:
        outList.append(0)

df['2_rows_forward_moving_tag'] = pd.Series(outList)
```

Output:

```
    0  1  2_rows_forward_moving_tag
0   9  4                          1
1   5  4                          1
2   1  3                          0
3  26  7                          0
```